# Facing issues while setting and resetting values in JSF bean

Tags: javascript, java, jsf, dojo

I am working on a JSF project which helps a user to create new account. In a page I have two radio buttons as;

```
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{accountBeans.radioData}" onClick="Common.showRadioButton(value)">
  <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="Item 1" />
  <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="Item 2" />             
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

onclick it is going to a javascript function defined in Common.js. In accountBeans.java getter and setter method are give to set the value in the bean as;

```
public String radioData = null;

public String getRadioData() {
    return radiodata;
}

public void setRadioData(String radioData) {
    this.radioData = radioData;
}
```

When the user lands on this page for the first time both radio button should be unselected. For this to happen I have created a method *reinitilize* in accountBeans which resets the value of radioData to null instead of using the previously stored value.

The problem that I am facing with this approach is when user navigates to other page after selecting a radio button and comes back to the same page the value is reseted. I need the user selected value to remain untill the account is created.

If I don't use the reinitialize method to reset the stored value, then while creating a new account the previously stored value is still retained which is a problem. Can anyone please tell me, how to retain the radioData value untill the account is created and then, going for new account creation the radioData value to be null again.

Comment: Part of a java bean standard is to use encapsulation, why is your property `public` ?  Please also add what bean scope you are using. I suppose you're using JSF ManagedBeans ? since CDI would just throw you an error regarding the public field

Comment: Yes, I am using JSF Managed Beans. It is not throwing any error for the public field.

Comment: Can you show the code for `Common.showradio...` please

Comment: I have a switch case defined in it, which gives  with case "1": and case "2"

Comment: Is your bean  a View or Request   scope ? in each page ..

Comment: @RequestScoped is used, not sure though as the code is in my friends system. Will have to check tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

> When the user lands on this page for the first time both radio button
>   should be unselected. For this to happen I have created a method
>   reinitilize in accountBeans which resets the value of radioData to
>   null instead of using the previously stored value.

This happens automatically, you don't have to do anything since it is the first time invoking the `accountsBean`.

Anyways, still waiting for your reply on the bean scopes that you are using but since you are using your our JS function to what I suppose is a redirect to the other page, you're gonna have to use request parameters:

Suppose you have something like the following in your JS file:

```
switch(value){
 case 1: window.location.href = "pageX.xhtml";
  break;
 case 2: window.location.href = "pageY.xhtml";
  break;
}
```

Then just append the value as a request param:

```
"page.xhtml?radioData="+value;
```

Then in both Facelet you can access the request params via:

```
  <h:head>
    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="radioData" value="#{bean.radioData}" />
    </f:metadata>
  </h:head>
```

This way the selected data will be kept:

```
<h:link outcome="/index" includeViewParams="true" value="Back" />
```

or

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton value="Back" action="/index?faces-redirect=true&amp;includeViewParams=true" />
</h:form>
```

The `includeViewParams=true` sets the same request parameters for the next redirect.

Comment: In the cases of switch statement, I am not redirecting to other pages. Both options shows a DOJO popup.

Comment: Also while creating new account the previously stored value is being displayed. Don't know how